# Почему содержимое динамически добавляемого элемента dom не отрабатывает на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

На сайт `wordpress` подключил онлайн чат **jivosite**, который загружается по скроллу.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'external_components_before_closing_tag_body', 20);
function external_components_before_closing_tag_body() {?>
  <script>
    jQuery(window).one('scroll', function () {
      <!-- jivosite -->
      jQuery('body').append("<!-- jivosite --><script> (function () {\n" +
        "        var widget_id = 'xxxx0000';\n" +
        "        var d = document;\n" +
        "        var w = window;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        function l() {\n" +
        "          var s = document.createElement('script');\n" +
        "          s.type = 'text/javascript';\n" +
        "          s.async = true;\n" +
        "          s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/' + widget_id;\n" +
        "          var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];\n" +
        "          ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        if (d.readyState == 'complete') {\n" +
        "          l();\n" +
        "        } else {\n" +
        "          if (w.attachEvent) {\n" +
        "            w.attachEvent('onload', l);\n" +
        "          } else {\n" +
        "            w.addEventListener('load', l, false);\n" +
        "          }\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      })();<\/script><!-- /jivosite -->");
      <!-- /jivosite -->
    });
  </script>
<?}
```

На `jquery` отрабатывает так как нужно, пробую переписать на `javascript`

```
var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
elemDiv.innerHTML = "..."
window.document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
```

код на странице выводится, но сам `jivosite` не подгружается - почему и как это поправить?

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'external_components_before_closing_tag_body', 20);
function external_components_before_closing_tag_body() {?>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
      elemDiv.innerHTML = "<!-- jivosite --><script> (function () {\n" +
        "        var widget_id = 'xxxx0000';\n" +
        "        var d = document;\n" +
        "        var w = window;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        function l() {\n" +
        "          var s = document.createElement('script');\n" +
        "          s.type = 'text/javascript';\n" +
        "          s.async = true;\n" +
        "          s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/' + widget_id;\n" +
        "          var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];\n" +
        "          ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        if (d.readyState == 'complete') {\n" +
        "          l();\n" +
        "        } else {\n" +
        "          if (w.attachEvent) {\n" +
        "            w.attachEvent('onload', l);\n" +
        "          } else {\n" +
        "            w.addEventListener('load', l, false);\n" +
        "          }\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      })();<\/script><!-- /jivosite -->";
      window.document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
      this.removeEventListener('scroll', arguments.callee);
    });
  </script>
<?}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал через создание тега `script`. Или быть может есть у кого-либо другие соображения по этому поводу? (комментарии не сохраняются)

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'external_components_before_closing_tag_body', 20);
function external_components_before_closing_tag_body() {?>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      var elemDiv = "(function () {\n" +
        "        var widget_id = 'wx0JFF7vYo';\n" +
        "        var d = document;\n" +
        "        var w = window;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        function l() {\n" +
        "          var s = document.createElement('script');\n" +
        "          s.type = 'text/javascript';\n" +
        "          s.async = true;\n" +
        "          s.src = '//code.jivosite.com/script/widget/' + widget_id;\n" +
        "          var ss = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];\n" +
        "          ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s, ss);\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        if (d.readyState == 'complete') {\n" +
        "          l();\n" +
        "        } else {\n" +
        "          if (w.attachEvent) {\n" +
        "            w.attachEvent('onload', l);\n" +
        "          } else {\n" +
        "            w.addEventListener('load', l, false);\n" +
        "          }\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      })();";
      script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(elemDiv));
      window.document.body.appendChild(script);
      this.removeEventListener('scroll', arguments.callee);
    });
  </script>
```